# Google Sheets - setFormulaR1C1(formula) doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm really scratching my head over this one. Everything seems to indicate I can use this structure, but Google Sheets doesn't recognize it, and if the function is supposed to parse it into A1 notation, it isn't.

Assume a spreadsheet with one row and two columns, and a number between 1 and 10 is in column 1.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var theCell = sheet.getRange(1,2,1,1);
theCell.setFormulaR1C1('=IF(R[0]C[-1]>=10, "Hooray!", "Boo!")');
```

This successfully sets the cell's value to '=IF(R[0]C[-1]>=10, "Hooray!", "Boo!")', but this doesn't parse (#ERROR!). Manually entering something simple like '=R[0]C[-1]' doesn't work either. So I'm very confused. Does R1C1 notation even work?

I can't even get Google's own example to work.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulasR1C1(String)

Edit:
The fix was to change the comas in the formula to semi-colons. Thanks AdamJ.

Comment: Copied everything and worked here. Please clarify the part: `This successfully sets the cell's value to '=IF(R[0]C[-1]>=10, "Hooray!", "Boo!")', but this doesn't parse (#ERROR!)`, it throws `(#ERROR!)` or don't, if it doens't, why would you like to receive an error?

Comment: If your spreadsheet locale uses commas for decimal separators, you will need to use semi-colons as argument separators in your formula: `=IF(R[0]C[-1]>=10;"Hooray!";"Boo!")`

Comment: @AdamL That was it! Switching to semi-colons worked. I wasn't aware Australia (the closest locale) used comas for decimal separators. Thanks a lot for the assist.

Comment: *I wasn't aware Australia (the closest locale) used comas for decimal separators*... hmmm, Australia doesn't use commas for decimals - though Austria does, I think.

Comment: Instead of editing the question for adding the answer, post an answer. (yes, you can answer your own question).